# Twirl: tags/views with optional content

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.3, twirl

I want to create a tag with optional content... Let's say that I have a tag:

**app/views/tags/part.scala.html**:

```scala
@(param: String)(content: Html = null)

@if(content == null) {
    @param: Your tag has no content...
} else {
    @param: @content
}
```

And I'd like to use it in my views as:

```scala
@tags.part("foo"){ <b>Good!</b} }
```

or

```scala
@tags.part("bar")
```

Unfortunately second call gives me the compilation error:

> missing arguments for method apply in object part;
>
> follow this method with `_' if you want to treat it as a partially applied function

How can I pass it without using `@tags.part("bar"){ }`  or `@tags.part("bar"){_}` (and check in tag `if body != "_"`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your call:

```
@tags.part("bar")
```

is curry call - it returns function apply - not a object.

The solution for your code is call apply function:

```
@tags.part("bar")()
```

If you want to call:

```
@tags.part("bar")
```

you should to define

```
@(param: String)(implicit content: Html)
```

and define implicit Html in context, or define as

```
@(param: String,content: Html = null)
```

- but then you have to call:

`@tags.part("foo")(Html("<b>Good!</b>"))` - what is error prone.

The work around for last solution is to create method and call it:

```
@good = {<b>Good!</b>}

@tags.part("foo")(good)
```